# I can't get the same ANOVA with aov and ezANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

I am trying to perform Mauchly's test of sphericity on a set of Data for which I have done a repeated-measures ANOVA using aov. I wanted to test the "Participant" as an independant variable, as in my experiment, participants who are presented with the same system will not perceive it the same way. My anova therefore looks like

```
res.aov <- aov(Attribute~System+Participant+Repetition
+System:Participant+System:Repetition+Participant:Repetition,data=sample1Norm)
```

which gives me the following summary:

```
                        Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
System                   6   6721  1120.2   2.723 0.0168 *
Participant              9      0     0.0   0.000 1.0000  
Repetition               2      0     0.0   0.000 1.0000  
System:Participant      54  32531   602.4   1.464 0.0475 *
System:Repetition       12   4877   406.4   0.988 0.4653  
Participant:Repetition  18      0     0.0   0.000 1.0000  
Residuals              108  44432   411.4                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, if I try to do the same with ezANOVA, I am not sure how to affect "Participant" as an independant variable:

```
ezANOVA(data=sample1Norm, dv=.(Attribute), wid=.(Participant), 
within=.(Repetition,System), detailed=TRUE, type=1)
```

gives me the following result:

```
$ANOVA
             Effect DFn DFd          SSn          SSd         F         p p<.05          ges
1        Repetition   2  18 5.446667e-07 2.187057e-05 0.2241368 0.8014030       7.076965e-12
2            System   6  54 6.720992e+03 3.253121e+04 1.8594123 0.1048659       8.031364e-02
3 Repetition:System  12 108 4.876884e+03 4.443211e+04 0.9878433 0.4652740       5.959033e-02
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

(and here's the data)

```
Participant,Repetition,System,Attribute

1,1,1,44

1,1,2,67

1,1,3,67

1,1,4,16

1,1,5,54

1,1,6,84

1,1,7,18

1,2,1,50.286

1,2,2,52.286

1,2,3,74.286

1,2,4,48.286

1,2,5,72.286

1,2,6,31.286

1,2,7,21.286

1,3,1,43.143

1,3,2,49.143

1,3,3,60.143

1,3,4,24.143

1,3,5,71.143

1,3,6,64.143

1,3,7,38.143

2,1,1,50

2,1,2,50

2,1,3,50

2,1,4,50

2,1,5,50

2,1,6,50

2,1,7,50

2,2,1,47.143

2,2,2,52.143

2,2,3,47.143

2,2,4,47.143

2,2,5,47.143

2,2,6,60.143

2,2,7,49.143

2,3,1,50

2,3,2,50

2,3,3,50

2,3,4,50

2,3,5,50

2,3,6,50

2,3,7,50

3,1,1,70.286

3,1,2,47.286

3,1,3,28.286

3,1,4,69.286

3,1,5,38.286

3,1,6,52.286

3,1,7,44.286

3,2,1,27.857

3,2,2,36.857

3,2,3,72.857

3,2,4,55.857

3,2,5,48.857

3,2,6,46.857

3,2,7,60.857

3,3,1,84.714

3,3,2,49.714

3,3,3,85.714

3,3,4,44.714

3,3,5,18.714

3,3,6,17.714

3,3,7,48.714

4,1,1,65.286

4,1,2,51.286

4,1,3,40.286

4,1,4,16.286

4,1,5,78.286

4,1,6,50.286

4,1,7,48.286

4,2,1,34.286

4,2,2,74.286

4,2,3,75.286

4,2,4,48.286

4,2,5,61.286

4,2,6,22.286

4,2,7,34.286

4,3,1,85.143

4,3,2,55.143

4,3,3,47.143

4,3,4,39.143

4,3,5,66.143

4,3,6,49.143

4,3,7,8.1429

5,1,1,39.286

5,1,2,49.286

5,1,3,44.286

5,1,4,47.286

5,1,5,47.286

5,1,6,61.286

5,1,7,61.286

5,2,1,45.429

5,2,2,55.429

5,2,3,47.429

5,2,4,47.429

5,2,5,53.429

5,2,6,54.429

5,2,7,46.429

5,3,1,48.857

5,3,2,47.857

5,3,3,52.857

5,3,4,48.857

5,3,5,47.857

5,3,6,51.857

5,3,7,51.857

6,1,1,83.571

6,1,2,19.571

6,1,3,60.571

6,1,4,53.571

6,1,5,14.571

6,1,6,68.571

6,1,7,49.571

6,2,1,130.86

6,2,2,24.857

6,2,3,4.8571

6,2,4,13.857

6,2,5,130.86

6,2,6,32.857

6,2,7,11.857

6,3,1,24.286

6,3,2,61.286

6,3,3,100.29

6,3,4,5.2857

6,3,5,100.29

6,3,6,41.286

6,3,7,17.286

7,1,1,65.429

7,1,2,14.429

7,1,3,84.429

7,1,4,25.429

7,1,5,77.429

7,1,6,12.429

7,1,7,70.429

7,2,1,42.429

7,2,2,74.429

7,2,3,80.429

7,2,4,68.429

7,2,5,35.429

7,2,6,-8.5714

7,2,7,57.429

7,3,1,91.286

7,3,2,23.286

7,3,3,77.286

7,3,4,-12.714

7,3,5,59.286

7,3,6,67.286

7,3,7,44.286

8,1,1,51.143

8,1,2,58.143

8,1,3,58.143

8,1,4,18.143

8,1,5,58.143

8,1,6,50.143

8,1,7,56.143

8,2,1,44.429

8,2,2,48.429

8,2,3,52.429

8,2,4,50.429

8,2,5,52.429

8,2,6,52.429

8,2,7,49.429

8,3,1,60.429

8,3,2,53.429

8,3,3,60.429

8,3,4,-3.5714

8,3,5,60.429

8,3,6,57.429

8,3,7,61.429

9,1,1,55.429

9,1,2,30.429

9,1,3,62.429

9,1,4,52.429

9,1,5,40.429

9,1,6,52.429

9,1,7,56.429

9,2,1,50.286

9,2,2,52.286

9,2,3,48.286

9,2,4,45.286

9,2,5,51.286

9,2,6,47.286

9,2,7,55.286

9,3,1,42.857

9,3,2,59.857

9,3,3,60.857

9,3,4,32.857

9,3,5,46.857

9,3,6,45.857

9,3,7,60.857

10,1,1,45

10,1,2,44

10,1,3,45

10,1,4,83

10,1,5,50

10,1,6,53

10,1,7,30

10,2,1,48.571

10,2,2,41.571

10,2,3,36.571

10,2,4,83.571

10,2,5,45.571

10,2,6,40.571

10,2,7,53.571

10,3,1,55.286

10,3,2,28.286

10,3,3,52.286

10,3,4,105.29

10,3,5,30.286

10,3,6,53.286

10,3,7,25.286
```

Bonus question: why am I not getting the details of the results (including Mauchly's test of sphericity)?

Thanks!

Laurent